# how to update the new module in openerp 7 in ubuntu 12.0?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, postgresql-9.1

Done,all the possible ways for updating the new module in openerp 7 in ubuntu 12.0.

Is there any other way to update the new module in openerp 7 in ubuntu 12.0 ?

```
   can anyone help me..
```

Answer (score 1):

- Put your module under **addons/** directory
- restart your server
- Go to **OpenERP Menu** Setting -> Modules -> Update Modules List and Update than
- Go to **OpenERP Menu** Setting -> Modules -> Installed Modules and search your module name

Hope this will help you to find your module.

And Still you Not Find your module than

- Left click on module go to Properties
- Give Permissions to Fill access: Read and Write
- Apply Permission to Enclosed Files

Comment: I have already tried the  above procedure but i am not able to view the module in  installed modules section.Is there an

Comment: give permission for that i think might be use for that and check ___openerp___.py file and i edit into in my answer

Comment: have you try to give permission of module? and your code is correct.

Comment: ya,i tried but there is no permission to access and the code is correct.

Comment: give permission to all files and folder also. Because i face the same problem. And solve to give permission.

Comment: I have given the permission to all files and folders and it is not updating the new module .But it is updating the new module in windows.Any other suggestions