# Error in installing new module in openerp

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I am using OpenERP 7.0-20130811-231021 in Ubuntu. I developed a new module but when I try to install it, that module is not in the OpenERP module list. I tried the following steps:

1. sudo /etc/init.d/openerp start
2. update modules list
3. go to installed module and viewed the module.

It is not there when I tried this command:

```
sudo ./openerp-server -u modulename
```

It shows the following:

> error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you kill process it of that ??

Comment: can you show the init and openerp file

Answer (score 1):

Find openerp-server process id:-

- **ps -ax | grep openerp-server** this will give the process id and need to kill it for example 1234

Kill Process ID:-

- **sudo kill -9 1234**

Start Sever:-

- **sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server start**

And update module from the GUI, Hope this will help you.

Comment: Mr.Odedra still its not working my module is not show on module list, can you help me again

Comment: sure, have you have db name ?? like sudo ./openerp-server -u modulename -d dbname, visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966389/how-to-update-the-new-module-in-openerp-7-in-ubuntu-12-0 and follow the steps, hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a custom module in OpenERP 7, it must first be in the addons directory.

Go to Settings > Modules > Update Modules List Click Update You must have Technical Features enabled for the user you are logged in as.

Then go to Settings > Modules > Installed Modules Remove the [Installed] filter and search for your custom module

Custom modules will not appear in Settings > Modules > Apps because that view will only display Modules/Apps that are found online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

1- Your openerp-server.conf in install file, in there you should check that your addons_path reference your module location

2-Check your **openerp**.py and make shure everything is rigth

3- You must check also your Run Configurations Parameters and specified -u and module name, this will update your module in every restart