# My module is not displayed in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

In my local `openerp`, my module display well. but in server `openerp` it's not displaying, even added server `addons` path. and i checked server path is correct. then what's error?

Comment: can you please check your __openerp__.py file.

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966389/how-to-update-the-new-module-in-openerp-7-in-ubuntu-12-0 hope this will help you

Comment: i check as you said. but there is no changed

Comment: can you paste the content of __openerp__.py file here?

Answer (score 1):

first update module list than refresh your browser 
and also check your **openerp**.py file

Answer (score 1):

try this command to understand where your actually module are place for example

- Run this command

  ```
  ps -ax | grep openerp-server
  ```
- For example above command gives

  ```
  804 ?        Sl    36:52 python /opt/openerp/server/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf
  ```
- Now we see that actually all module are kept at this place  **/opt/openerp/server/addons**. If we give wrong path of module that obvious it will not show in the module list.

So First understand where all module are run at server and than find module. And visit this might be helpful for you. [how to update the new module in openerp 7 in ubuntu 12.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966389/how-to-update-the-new-module-in-openerp-7-in-ubuntu-12-0/20966551#20966551)

Best Regards, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Do check your **openerp**.py file is proper or not. in that Please check weather module is installable or not.

```
{
...
      'installable': True,
...
}
```

If it seems good then you need to check the access rights for your module folder under addons. it should be executable. if it's not executable then give access rights using

```
sudo chmod 775 -R Module_name
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Find the module this way,

Update the module list in `Settings`,

`Settings --> Installed Modules` and remove the search word **installed** in filter box and finally search with your module name in filter box.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I searched by this way but my module does not appear

Comment: @user3145948 I think you need to change the folder permissions

Comment: drwxr_xr_x this is my file permission

Comment: Try this command `./server/openerp-server --addons-path=addons,web/addons,server/openerp/addons`

Comment: change the permission from drwxr_xr_x to drwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 0):

Usually i paste my module on /usr/share/pyshare/openerp/addons.
After change my directory like /usr/local/lib/python2.7/openerp/addons, My module is displaying in openerp.